# Exportar datos a excel con ag-grid

Tags: angular, excel, aggrid

Tengo una tabla en la cual varias columnas se auto-generan con un bucle

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.exercise.profiles.length; i++) {
  newColumns[i + 2] = {
    colId: `p${i}`,
    field: `rebalanceFind`,
    headerName: this.exercise.profiles![i].profileName,
    valueFormatter: params => {
      if (typeof params.value[i] === 'undefined' || params.value[i] === '-') {
        params.value[i] = '-';
        return params.value[i];
      } else {
        params.value[i] = this.currencyFormatter.format(params.value[i])
        return params.value[i];
      }
    }
  };
}
```

rebalanceFind es un array que dependiendo del número de columnas tiene más o menos campos, os dejo un pedazo de json para que se entienda a lo que me refiero:

```
{
  "idx": 3,
  "rebalance": "-17.156.494,10 €",
  "total": -54451381.690000005,
  "rebalanceFind": [
    "-17.156.494,10 €",
    "-37.294.887,59 €",
    "-",
    "-",
    "-"
  ]
}
```

En el front se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se va rellenando con los datos del array, el problema viene al exportar a excel, cuando exporto a excel se me vuelca todo en la misma celda, por que claro está imprimiendo rebalanceFind de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo necesito que si en la columna Prueba3 aparece un - ,cuando exporte a excel aparezca ese guion y no el array

Espero haberme explicado y muchas gracias!